# Extension builder overwrite fe_user TCA

Tags: typo3, extbase

If I try to extend fe_user table by creating a new Model Object on extension builder in Typo3 6.1.7, it overwrites TCA by writing those lines in ext_tables.php of my extension:

```
\TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\ExtensionManagementUtility::addLLrefForTCAdescr('fe_users', 'EXT:voiwizard/Resources/Private/Language/locallang_csh_fe_users.xlf');
\TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\ExtensionManagementUtility::allowTableOnStandardPages('fe_users');
$TCA['fe_users'] = array(
    'ctrl' => array(
        'title' => 'LLL:EXT:voiwizard/Resources/Private/Language/locallang_db.xlf:fe_users',
        'label' => 'prova',
        'tstamp' => 'tstamp',
        'crdate' => 'crdate',
        'cruser_id' => 'cruser_id',
        'dividers2tabs' => TRUE,

        'versioningWS' => 2,
        'versioning_followPages' => TRUE,
        'origUid' => 't3_origuid',
        'languageField' => 'sys_language_uid',
        'transOrigPointerField' => 'l10n_parent',
        'transOrigDiffSourceField' => 'l10n_diffsource',
        'delete' => 'deleted',
        'enablecolumns' => array(
            'disabled' => 'hidden',
            'starttime' => 'starttime',
            'endtime' => 'endtime',
        ),
        'searchFields' => 'prova,',
        'dynamicConfigFile' => \TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\ExtensionManagementUtility::extPath($_EXTKEY) . 'Configuration/TCA/User.php',
        'iconfile' => \TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\ExtensionManagementUtility::extRelPath($_EXTKEY) . 'Resources/Public/Icons/fe_users.gif'
    ),
);
```

This code overwrites the original fe_users's TCA configuration and the back-end [website user][1] table becomes inaccessible.
Is there any way to prevent this or do I have to delete those lines every time I want to save the changes in the extension builder?

Comment: Please add your edit as answer and accept it by clicking the check sign. This way it's a community wiki that you answered yourself.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I've found an error in my relationship:

To properly extend fe_users table with a Model Object in Extension Builder, I had to "extend existing model class" \TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Domain\Model\FrontendUser instead of "map to existing table" fe_users.

[image]

In this way, everything works as expected!